# Why is a Cloud Service still available on internet after being deployed in a Virtual Network?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

I have created a Virtual Network, when deploying a VM in it, it's unavailable from Internet, and available when I connect via VPN. (And that's what it's supposed to do).

But when I deploy a Cloud Service (and the Cloud Service is correctly deployed in the Virtual Network as I can see it in the VN resources list), it's still available from Internet.

How can I secure the access of a Cloud Service ? I don't want it to be accessible by every one, just by VPN and from dedicated IPs.

Comment: downvoters, please explain what's wrong with my question...

Comment: How is it still available? What ports? What endpoints have you defined?

Comment: Finally I found how to configure ACL in cloud services: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walterm/archive/2014/04/22/windows-azure-paas-acls-are-here.aspx 
So it resolve my issue. :)

Comment: @NicoC - if you resolved your issue, post the resolution as an answer. Or delete this question. Otherwise, it sits as an unanswered question. Also: Please expand upon what your actual issue was. I'm guessing you had an endpoint open (because you mentioned ACL's). It's important to include these details.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that by default Cloud Services have EndPoints configured. By adding ACLs to it (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walterm/archive/2014/04/22/windows-azure-paas-acls-are-here.aspx) I can isolate them into the Virtual Network.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the cloud service to be accessible from the Internet, the better way to protect is to remove the endpoints. If you want to ACL the instances at the Virtual Network/Subnet level consider using this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/)